# How do I reset my local repo back to origin/master in SourceTree?

Tags: git

My local repo is ahead of the remote. In the SourceTree view, my local repo (top line) is ahead of remote, or "origin/master" (second line) by 9 commits.

This is confirmed with git status:
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 9 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean

But, I don't want to just do a git push because I want to put my 9 commits on a branch or feature.

Specifically, I want to:
- reset my local install back to origin/master
- add a new feature or branch that splits off from the master
- commit my changes
- push the feature branch

I'm confused about the first step: Resetting my local back to the origin/master. 
I believe a rebase would do this from command line but how would I do this within SourceTree?

I've searched this topic and answers advise a 'git push', but I want to do the push from the new feature branch, all in SourceTree.

Thanks.

Comment: So, the question is:  do you want to discard or keep the changes?

Comment: I'd like to keep my changes (the 9 commits), if possible, and put them on a new branch, after resetting my local install back to origin/master.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First if you want to keep your current changes and set them to a remote branch do this:

```
git commit -a -m "Save all my work on this branch"
git branch saveThisFeature
```

(you can name the branch anything btw)

Then if you want to reset the master branch to the last push you need to do this:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Then you can view your master branch that you are on or switch over to the saveThis branch by:

```
git checkout saveThisFeature
```

Here is a quick explanation of the -a and -m git options:

-m Commit changes to head (but not yet to the remote repository)

-a Commit any files you've added with git add, and also commit any files you've changed since then

Answer (score 2):

Since you haven't pushed anything, this will make it somewhat easy.  Note that I'm not using any UI tools since I'm more familiar with the  command line.

```
git reset HEAD~9
git checkout -b <branch-name>
git add .
git commit
```

The `reset` introduces a mixed mode reset; you won't lose any of your work, but it will move the head pointer of your master branch back 9 commits.

If the work you have is where it should be; that is, the work that should have been on its own branch now is, then you should look to force-push your master branch, thus overwriting history.  Be careful:  if **anyone else** has built their work off of the tip of master, they will have to rebase their work against your new branch instead.

Comment: I like the simplicity of this solution. I did the git reset~9 which successfully put me on the master. But also told me I am now 5 behind and can fast-forward and 'git pull' to update my local branch. So, I did a git pull which gave me errors about local changes that would be overwritten by merge. (I probably should have done the git checkout -b before the pull).
Can I do the git checkout -b <branch-name> at this point? If it's less complicated to just overwrite my local changes, that would be OK - I have backups.

Comment: Right, I suppose that's the next part of it.  (I wrote the above while I was on a plane there...)  Anyway, I believed that you wanted to rewrite your history as if the nine commits were never on master, so you would want to actually force-push your master branch to your remote repo.  Before you do that, be sure that everyone's cool with it, though, as rewriting history usually messes with someone's day.